# UI won't display when entering my app from a VOIP call received in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, background, voip

I'm having a little confusion in regards to showing my UI when opening the app from an incoming background video call. I am successfully causing iOS to summon the default "incoming video call" interface when the app is in the background, but after the call is answered, my app isn't being woken up properly?

When I receive the call push, I setup a CXProvider and notify CallKit of an incoming call:

```
    func handleIncomingCallFromBackground() {
        //These properties are parsed from the push payload before this method is triggered
        guard let callingUser = callingUser, roomName != nil else {
            print("Unexpected nil caller and roomname (background)")
            return
        }

        let callHandleTitle = "\(callingUser.first_name) \(callingUser.surname)"

        let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration.default
        let callKitProvider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
        callKitProvider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)

        let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: callHandleTitle)
        self.callHandle = callHandle

        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate.default
        callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle

        let callUUID = UUID()
        self.callUUID = callUUID

        callKitProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: callUUID, update: callUpdate) { error in
            if error != nil {
                self.resetTwilioObjects()
            }
        }
    }
```

I respond to the answer call delegate method for the CXProvider, in which I get an access token for the video call from the server, send a response to the server to alert the caller that we've accepted the call, and perform a segue to our own video call controller (that's all *jobsVC.showVideoCallVC()* does) which handles connecting the call through a Twilio room etc. Code below.

```
 func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        guard let customer = callingUser, let callHandle = self.callHandle, let uuid = callUUID, let roomName = roomName else {
            resetTwilioObjects()
            return
        }

        self.twilioAPI = TwilioAPI()
        self.twilioAPI!.accessToken(room: roomName) { (success, accessToken) in
            switch success{
            case true:
                guard let token = accessToken else {
                    return
                }

                let customerID = customer.userID

                DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() , execute: {
                    self.twilioAPI!.postResponse(customerID: customerID, status: 1) { (success) in
                        if let success = success, !success {
                            self.resetTwilioObjects()
                        }
                    }
                })

                guard let jobsVC = P_ChildHomeJobsVC.instance else {
                    print("Jobs VC unexpectedly nil")
                    return
                }

                //All this method does is perform a segue, the parameters are stored for later.
                jobsVC.showVideoCallVC(callingUser: customer, callHandle: callHandle, callKitProvider: provider, callUUID: uuid, twilioAccessToken: token, roomName: roomName)
                action.fulfill()

            default:
                action.fail()
                self.resetTwilioObjects()
            }
        }
    }
```

Depending on whether or not the device is locked, I get differing behaviour:

- If the device is locked, upon hitting my app icon to open the app, I get the latest app screenshot show up with a green bar at the top instead of the UI.
- If the device is unlocked, upon hitting my app icon to open the app nothing happens at all - it stays on the iOS interface.

According to my logs, the segue is actually being performed correctly and the inner workings of the video call controller are even being fired, but shortly after I get the *applicationWillResignActive:* delegate call and everything stops.

What's odd (or maybe not) is that if the device is locked whilst the app is still in the foreground, everything works as expected: the app is correctly woken up and the updated UI is shown. I noticed that I still get the *applicationWillResignActive:* call, but immediately get *applicationDidBecomeActive:* after that.

Does anyone have any suggestions or hints as to what I might be doing wrong?